# Unable to get login with yodlee live account

Tags: yodlee

I am using yodlee live account on private zone.Yodlee gave me the cobrand username, password and Seperate URL for REST API.Already my server ip has got white listed in yodlee, but when i request the cobrand session token using provided credentials, it responses with following error,

```
"{"errorOccurred":"true","exceptionType":"com.yodlee.core.login.InvalidCobrandCredentialsException","referenceCode":"_4109c0df-5fbf-49fb-a970-aac64bb84ca4","message":"Invalid Cobrand Credentials","detailedMessage":null}"
```

Invalid Cobrand Credentials - But i have checked with my credentials, Its correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the private cobarand id, password etc on private zone, also it take a while to get IP white-listed usually up to a week. So you may need to wait for the same. If everything is correct at your side then follow the method below.

As you or your organization is a customer of Yodlee, so you need to raise a service request (SR) at Yodlee's support center using the given support authentication or perhaps via the contact person assigned. Yodlee can only resolve such issue via service requests only.

Comment: Already my IP is whitelisted two weeks before.how can raise a service request? there is no such service request form in yodlee site.only sales oriented form is available.

Comment: You may find the details of support site in the communication recived from yodlee. It is usually send in a document after the contract is signed. do please check all mails you've received from Yodlee after the contract has been signed. if you can not find the same then use the emails you have specified as contact person to Yodlee for requesting the same and also request the support site link and credentials.

Comment: Thanks for yodlee support team.Problem due to IP whitelising. Thanks to @apoorv (Yodlee Engineer) to help us for fixing this problem - http://stackoverflow.com/users/1001603/apoorv

Answer (score 0):

Yes , Pushparaj is right, this is caused due to invalid credentials and has nothing to do with IP whitelisting. Please get in touch with the Yodlee contact who provided you the credentials, so that this can be corrected.